# Google Map Fragment padding

Tags: android

I've got Activity with MapFragment and simple LenearLayout with buttons. On the image you can see little padding (about 3 dp and gray colored) between LienarLaouyt and Map. This padding belongs to mapFragment - i checked it by switching background color of main layout and linear layout. How can i remove it?

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/select_period_button_label"
            android:id="@+id/fragmentHistory_selectPeriodButton"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/control_button_selector"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/track_button_label"
            android:id="@+id/fragmentHistory_trackButton"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/control_button_selector"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/activityDeviceCurrentLocation_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This...

```
   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/activityDeviceCurrentLocation_map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

Comment: if you find this code work then you can accept my answer.. @ЕвгенийКравцов